# Installing a package (conda) results in ImportError: Library not loaded

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, package, importerror

I installed seaborn package through conda:

```
~user: conda install seaborn

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
seaborn:     0.8-py27_0      
The following packages will be UPDATED:
conda:       4.3.8-py27_0     --> 4.3.30-py27h407ed3a_0
matplotlib:  1.4.3-np19py27_2 --> 1.5.3-np111py27_1    
statsmodels: 0.6.1-np19py27_0 --> 0.8.0-np111py27_0
```

And it messed up my matplotlib installation, now when I run my python script, it raises an error when importing matplotlib:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so
Reason: Incompatible library version: _png.so requires version 39.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 34.0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error can be caused by old version of conda. You need to first update conda and then try again.

```
conda update conda
```

Comment: Worked :) Thanks for solving this dependency nightmare !

Comment: @Charlotte I guess its should be marked varified if worked for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from your conda command prompt:

conda install -c anaconda seaborn

Comment: by 'conda command prompt' you mean the terminal console right?

And so it says: 
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    seaborn:   0.8.0-py27h92884e4_0  anaconda

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

    conda:     4.3.30-py27h407ed3a_0          --> 4.3.30-py27h407ed3a_0 anaconda
    conda-env: 2.6.0-0                        --> 2.6.0-h36134e3_0      anaconda